# Where are my barrel adjusters for my shifting cables?

Tags: derailleur, adjustment

I have a [Devinci Caribou I](http://www.devinci.com/bikes/browse_13#13_44_161) and I was trying to adjust the front derailleur. I got the top and bottom stops adjusted right, but it seems that it doesn't downshift correctly from the biggest cog to the intermediate cog.  From reading on the internet, I've seen recommendations to adjust the barrel adjustment to fine tune the derailer. Only problem is I can't find the barrel adjustment.  The shifter cables come right out the side of the brifters, and there's no adjustment there. They go through the frame, and come out near the bottom bracket.  On the cable housing there's something that can be turned that seems like it could be a barrel adjuster, but turning it creates no changes in derailleur position.  This turnable part of the cable housing is present on both shifter cable. There is functioning barrel adjuster for my rear brakes, but this is quite different then the possible barrel adjustment for the shifter cables (and it actually works).  Can anybody help me out finding my barrel adjuster?  Here is a picture of the [model](http://matthewandtheride.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/fv125-caribou1.jpg) that I have, although it's hard to see any of the cabling in this picture.

Comment: If all else fails, take it to the shop where you bought it and ask them to show you the barrel adjusters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is  the black piece about 2 inches from where it enters the down tube.

That is the barrel adjuster, but in line adjusters can be difficult get started adjusting, as often they come from the factory with the 2 halves of the barrel adjuster turned tightly against each other.

That makes it appear to do nothing, when in fact the reason it is doing nothing is because it is rotating around the cable housing, rather than activating the adjustment.

Try to hold one half still, while rotating the barrel. Once it is broken free it should work normally. If not, then take it back to your LBS, and ask them to do it, as you will likely have to remove it from the bike to get it free.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It was indeed the barrel adjuster, but it was hard to get it going. There wasn't much to hold on to on the one side, but after some fiddling, I got it started. Fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there's an adjuster in-line, right before the cable enters the down tube.

Comment: Looking at the picture, I assume you mean the black piece about 2 inches from where it enters the down tube. This picture is different then mine, because mine is from the previous year, but that appears to be the same mechanism I have on my bike, that doesn't actually do anything.  Not sure if you can tell from the picture, but that mechanism is a different shape than the barrel adjuster on the brake cable that you see a little bit above that when you zoom in on the picture.  On my bike the "barrel adjuster" you see is actually located about 3 inches from where it comes out of the brifter arm.

Comment: That gizmo must be there for some reason.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't need too much adjustment in your FD via barrel adjustments. If your cable is stretched or your not getting clean shifting just readjust your FD, it doesn't take that long and there are a lot of tutorials out there:

http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustments

Comment: You need barrel adjusters because of cable stretch.  A brand new cable will need adjustment within a few days, and it's a royal PITA to try to reset the cable (exactly!) to get proper adjustment.  To quote the site you linked "To reduce gap, increase inner wire tension by turning *barrel adjuster* counter-clockwise."

Comment: i realize you need barrel adjusters, that's why i said "you shouldn't need MUCH adjustment". Additionally, adjusting a FD is not a royal PITA. I've adjusted mine over a lunch break from work. Anyway...all this is moot since his question has been answered above. They are right there above where his cables enter the frame. Most modern road setups don't have anything but a micro adjust barrel adjuster because you don't need anything else.